# Using a PDO COUNT query with parameters

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the following PDO query set up:

```
$CHECK_MATCH = $DBH->query("
    SELECT COUNT(*) as matches FROM users WHERE 
        username = :username AND password = :password
");
$CHECK_MATCH->bindParam(':username', $username);
$CHECK_MATCH->bindParam(':password', $password);
```

However, I recieve an error saying:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function bindParam() on a non-object
```

Why doesn't this work?
How would I retrieve the required values from the statement if i used `prepare` instead of `query`?

Comment: Why don't you enable PDO warnings? `->query` is meant for direct execution, not statement preparation.

Comment: Try `$DBH->prepare` instead of `$DBH->query`

Comment: I used `->query` so that I could grab values from the results. How would I get those values using a prepared statement?

Comment: You can get those values using `$row = $CHECK_MATCH->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this answer is not necessary because **Marc B**'s answer actually solve the prob. Well, since @proPhet requested for a complete solution, here it is:

```
$CHECK_MATCH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) as matches FROM users WHERE 
    username = :username AND password = :password");
$CHECK_MATCH->bindParam(':username', $username);
$CHECK_MATCH->bindParam(':password', $password);

$CHECK_MATCH->execute();
// Fetch as object
$row = $CHECK_MATCH->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

echo $row->matches;
```

Answer (score 3):

You didn't prepare a statement. You DIRECTLY executed a query. Since a placeholder-using query is NOT a valid query as far as `->query()` is concerned, the query failed, and returned a boolean FALSE. You then took that boolean FALSE and tried to treat it as an object.

The proper sequence is:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('.... your query here ...');
              ^^^^^^^----note the new method call
$stmt->bindParam(...);

$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to prepare the query:

```
$CHECK_MATCH = $DBH->prepare("  <------ Changed query for prepare
    SELECT COUNT(*) as matches FROM users WHERE 
        username = :username AND password = :password
");
$CHECK_MATCH->bindParam(':username', $username);
$CHECK_MATCH->bindParam(':password', $password);
```